# Adding data to an empty list from 'if' statements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, error-handling

I am working on a project using Python whereby I send out emails in bulk to a list of contacts in a CSV file.

I can get the email sending working fine but I want to be able to add some error handling if there are some missing values in the CSV file.

My CSV file simply includes: record_id, retailer, first_name, last_name and email.

I want to be able to capture these 'errors' using 'if' statements and add them to an empty list.

I will then use the populated list to store the information of what the missing values are so that I can use that list to present the errors elsewhere in the code (still unsure as to where I will want to display the errors).

The issue I am having is that I am unable to add the values in my 'if' statements to the empty list. It only prints the empty list.

Here is the sample of my code where the email sending section is:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    try:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
    except SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print("Username and/or password you entered is incorrect")
    try:
        with open("contacts.csv") as file: # Sending Multiple Personalized Emails using a CSV file
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            next(reader)  # Skip header row
            missing = []
            for record_id, retailer, first_name, last_name, email in reader:
                if not retailer:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has Retailer name missing!")
                    continue
                if not first_name:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has First name missing!")
                    continue
                if not last_name:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has Last name missing!")
                    continue
                if not email:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has Email missing!")
                    continue
                print(missing)
                server.sendmail(
                    sender_email,
                    email,
                    message.as_string().format(
                        record_id=record_id,
                        retailer=retailer,
                        first_name=first_name,
                        last_name=last_name,
                        email=email,
                        previous_month=previous_month,
                        year=year),
                )
        print("Emails sent!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Emails not sent!")
        print(e)
    except SMTPException as e2:
        print(e2)
```

Here is the sample CSV file:

```
record_id,retailer,first_name,last_name,email 
1,Store 1,Bob,Doe,example@example.com 
2,Store 2,Jane,Lang,example@example.com 
3,Store 3,Bill,Rowe,example@example.com 
4,Store 4,Rachel,Greene,, (missing email error test) 
5,Store 5,,Geller,example@example.com, (missing first name error test) 
6,,Joey,Tribiani,example@example.com (missing retailer error test)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your question boils down to "why is `if not retailer` false" (etc.) ? Have you examined the values of the variables you are using in the `if` statements?

Comment: could it be that all "errors" are appended only at the end (all the bad examples are at the end of the csv), in that case it won't print the list when anything is appended to it because of `continue`

Comment: Please always include a **portion** of the data in your [mre]. Specifically, a few lines from the file that your code is having trouble with. Copy and paste them in the question then format as code.

Comment: Why do you have two `if not retailer:` conditions? Since the first one executes `continue`, the second one will never be executed.

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for your input. You are correct in that i have placed the intentional 3 error rows at the end of the csv file. However when I use normal if statements with just 'print' instead of the 'append', the errors are printed to the console but it.s the .append that doesn't seem to work. Note: i have removed the 'continue' statements and updated the code.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for highlighting that. I have removed the duplicated error but still nothing. I have also removed the 'continue' statements and updated to code above.

Comment: ok, with the current example the easiest is to probably put `print(missing)` at the very end of the code, like after all is done, then it should print the full list, because those continue statements at the end of iterations will mean that it never prints the list after something has been appended, it will skip to the next iteration which will skip again until you finish the loop, just put `print(missing)` at the very end

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for your input. I have tried adding the print statement at the very end put it only prints the 1 error which is the 1st 'retailer' if error.

Comment: thanks everyone for your input. Barmar's response below has given me the solution that got me the results I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` statement skips over all the rest of the loop body and goes to the next iteration. If the first `if not retailer:` condition succeeds, you won't do any of the other tests.

Rather than executing `continue` in each `if` block, just set a variable that indicates whether that record is valid. This allows you to check all the fields. Then after all the checks, test this variable to see whether you should send the email.

`print(missing)` should be taken out of the loop. You're only printing it when all the validations succeed. Do it at the end to get all the errors.

Unrelated issue: the `except:` blocks in a `try` are tested in order, so you should have more specific exception types first. `except Exception:` should be the last block.

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    try:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
    except SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print("Username and/or password you entered is incorrect")
    try:
        with open("contacts.csv") as file: # Sending Multiple Personalized Emails using a CSV file
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            next(reader)  # Skip header row
            missing = []
            for record_id, retailer, first_name, last_name, email in reader:
                valid = True
                if not retailer:
                    missing.append("Testing")
                    valid = False
                if not retailer:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has Retailer name missing!")
                if not first_name:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has First name missing!")
                    valid = False
                if not last_name:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has Last name missing!")
                    valid = False
                if not email:
                    missing.append("Record ID " + record_id + " has Email missing!")
                    valid = False
                if valid:
                    server.sendmail(
                        sender_email,
                        email,
                        message.as_string().format(
                            record_id=record_id,
                            retailer=retailer,
                            first_name=first_name,
                            last_name=last_name,
                            email=email,
                            previous_month=previous_month,
                            year=year),
                    )
            print(missing)
        print("Emails sent!")
    except SMTPException as e2:
        print(e2)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Emails not sent!")
        print(e)
```

Comment: thanks for your input @barmar! I have made the code changes according to your recommendations but only 1 error is added to the list. I intentionally added 3 'wrong' rows in the csv file so 3 errors should be captured.

Comment: Please show a sample of the CSV file including the wrong rows.

Comment: I can't seem to post a screenshot but here this what it should be (top row are headers):

record_id,retailer,first_name,last_name,email

1,Store 1,Bob,Doe,example@example.com
2,Store 2,Jane,Lang,example@example.com
3,Store 3,Bill,Rowe,example@example.com
4,Store 4,Rachel,Greene,, (missing email error test)
5,Store 5,,Geller,example@example.com, (missing first name error test)
6,,Joey,Tribiani,example@example.com (missing retailer error test)

Comment: That's useless without formatting. Paste into a code block in the question.

Comment: apologies @barmar. This is my first time posting a question! I have edited the question and added the sample csv date. Hope this helps.

Comment: The Geller line has an extra `,`. That's causing an error that's caught by the `try/except`.

Comment: That aborts the rest of the loop and nothing gets printed.

Comment: apologies that was my typo as i manually typed it. I checked the csv file in notepad and the extra comma (,) is not appearing. With amended code above, I am only getting the 1 'error' returning which is the 1st IF statement for the 'Retailer'

Comment: When I fixed that I got the expected results.

Comment: make sure your empty fields don't have a space in them. Or use `strip()` to remove surrounding whitespace when testing a field.

Comment: what errors did you receive? I don't see an extra comma on my end. I only get 1 error which is for ID 6 (Joey)

Comment: `['Record ID 4 has Email missing!', 'Record ID 5 has First name missing!', 'Testing', 'Record ID 6 has Retailer name missing!']`

Comment: hmm this is weird as i can't seem to get the same results. I have checked that I have the same code as you kindly posted above but only get the 1 error.
['Record ID 6 has Retailer name missing!']                                                                                                                      
Emails sent!

Comment: Ahhhhh! I know where I went wrong. I have an additional 'missing' empty list just below where the 'valid = True' is defined. I removed that and got the same results! Thanks so much for your help and patience!